# Isolated storage in Linux

Tags: linux, isolatedstorage

In Windows we can save some information related to a particular application in isolated storage for application.

Can we have this same sort of storage or any other secure storage place to save information for applications in Linux?

Comment: Please define the level of 'secure' you are referring to.

Comment: According to MSDN "With isolated storage, data is always isolated by user and by assembly. Credentials such as the origin or the strong name of the assembly determine assembly identity. Data can also be isolated by application domain, using similar credentials."
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common is to have a hidden subdirectory in the users home directory, and store data there.

Comment: what if user did "rm -rf /userfolder/."

Comment: @Naresh What if the user did `del /F %AppData%` on the windows system?

Comment: @HonkyTonk thanks. It resolves "my own" mystery of Isolated Storage, Which is not Isolated..